# Send Transaction XDR To Other Account Using Stellar

Tags: transactions, java-sdk, xdr

**Situation:** I am trying to implement the [Stellar 2-party multisignature escrow account with time lock & recovery Smart Contract](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/walkthroughs/stellar-smart-contracts.html) example using the Java SDK. In transaction 3 (unlock transaction), the source needs to create and sign the transaction and then pass the signed transaction to the destination, so they can sign it.

**Question:** Is there a way I can pass the transaction XDR from the source to the destination account, so they can sign and return the transaction to the source using Stellar's Java SDK?

**What I Have Tried:**

- I experimented with the Transaction Memo, but that limits the number of bytes to 28, so I am unable to send the hash or XDR using this format
- I have tried to use the transaction hash, but it looks like you cannot use the Stellar transactions endpoint until that transaction has been submitted.

I have researched this issue, but I was unable to find an example containing how to send just the transaction XDR between accounts.

I appreciate any help that you can provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if SEP-0007 is what you want, but you can check the [Multisig section](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0007.md#multisig).